# Flutter: how to center a child, but set a limit on how big it can grow on one side of the margin

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a home/login screen which is made up of a column that fills the entire screen like so:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: Logo(),
      ),
    ),
    showThis ? This() : That(),
  ],
),
```

The second child of the column is dynamic and can have different heights, and this screen will have inputs so the keyboard will also affect the height.

I want to center `Logo()` vertically within the container when it's small (e.g. when keyboard is active), but limit how much the 'top margin' is able to grow, so that when the keyboard is hidden and `This()`/`That()` is small enough, `Logo()` will be in a static position on the screen, say 150 from the top (no longer centred vertically).

One method I have tried was using 2 empty `Expanded()` above and below `Logo()` and wrapping the top part in a `ConstraintedBox()`, but I am not able to get it to behave correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // constrain top spacing with a max height
          Flexible(child: Container(height: 160)),
          _logo(),
          Spacer(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    _bottomWidget(),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `Center()` and also if you wanna in a specific position use `Stack`, for example

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    showThis(), 
    Positioned(top: 150, child: Logo())
  ],
)
```